# Can I drag and drop an email to a sidebar gadget in gmail?

Tags: drag-and-drop, gmail, google-api

I want to make a sidebar gadget in gmail to which I can drag an email message and inside the gadget get the link to that message.

Can this be done?

I found one forum conversation about it with no clear answer.